# Swift Bond framework - many to one relationship - trigger a single command if anything changes

Tags: swift, frp, reactivekit, swiftbond

Consider the following example:

Given a set of observables:

```
let value1 = Observable(false)
let value2 = Observable(false)
let value3 = Observable(false)

let isSaveButtonEnabled = Observable(false)
```

I'd like to execute this code every time something changes:

```
func validate() {
{...}
isSaveButtonEnabled.value = true
}
```

Currently, the only way to configure such relationship is to individually add a closure to every Observable:

```
value1.onNext {
self.validate()
}

value2.onNext {
self.validate()
}

....
```

**The goal:**

I'd like to program it using syntax similar to this:

```
[value1, value2, value.....].onAnyChange {
self.validate()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I came up:

```
private func configureValidationLogic() {
    [vaule1.eraseType(), 
     vaule2.eraseType(),
    vaule3.eraseType(),
    vaule4.eraseType(),
    vaule5.eraseType()].forEach { (signal) in
        signal.observeNext { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            self.validate()
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe, there is a better (built-in into the library) approach of achieving the same.